# Box-shadow only on right and left

Tags: html, css

I need to make a box-shadow only on the right and left of an element. It should fade and get thinner to the top and bottom. It also shouldn't oveflow on top and bottom.

[image: box-shadow effect right and left]

The main issue is that I can't prevent the shadow to overflow on the top and bottom of the element.

This is what I have :

*HTML :*

```
<div></div>
```

*CSS :*

```
div{
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px 0px #000000;
}
```

Comment: “A rectangle” is not really unusual for a `<div>`…

Comment: @false I need a shadow of left and right side for a div...

Comment: Try this : http://www.paulund.co.uk/creating-different-css3-box-shadows-effects

Answer (score 17):

You will need to use **two box-shadows one for the left shadow and one for the right one**. You need to specify both box-shadows in the same box-shadow attribute and seperate them with a coma :

```
box-shadow: -60px 0px 100px -90px #000000, 60px 0px 100px -90px #000000;
```

Both need to have a negative spread value so they are shorter than the divs height and don't overflow on the top and bottom.
*[More info about box-shadow on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-shadow)*

**Output :**

[image: box-shadow only on the left and right]

You will need to tweak the values of the shadow in order to adapt it to the size of the element you want to use it on.

```css
div{
    height:500px;
    width:300px;
    margin:0 auto;
    box-shadow: -60px 0px 100px -90px #000000, 60px 0px 100px -90px #000000;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the most elegant semantical way must be to wrap that element inside a div, with `overflow-y: hidden;` and `padding: 0 [horizontal-spread-box-shadow]`. Here is the exaggerated example:

```css
body {
  padding: 50px;
}

.parent {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 2px solid red;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  padding: 0 40px;
}

.children {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 40px #000;
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="children"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use margin to show the shadow

```
div {margin:10px}
```

Look at this

http://jsfiddle.net/nB5F6/4/