# How do I get box shadow on only left and right side

Tags: css

I currently have global box shadow on a site -

```
box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0,0,0,.1);
```

But how do I modify the above so that it only appears on left or right side or both left and right?

Comment: Due to the question being closed, I wrote the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59302281/9787887)

Answer (score 1):

Remember that you can use negative values for spread and multiple values for box-shadow.

```css
.shadow {
  width: 30%;
  height: 40px;
  margin: 2rem;
  box-shadow:
  -5px 0px 5px -6px rgba(0,0,0,1),
  5px 0px 5px -6px rgba(0,0,0,1);
}
```

```html
<div class="shadow"></div>
```

Another solution could be to use ::before and ::after and filter: blur. The benefits here is that you can transform: rotate the shadows to make it look like the parent element is slightly tilting.

```css
.shadow {
  position: relative;
  margin: 2rem;
  width: 30%;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: white;
}

.shadow::before,
.shadow::after {
  z-index: -1;
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 2px;
  bottom: 2px;
  background-color: #000;
  width: 2px;
  filter: blur(2px);
}

.shadow::after {
  right: 0px;
}

.tilting.shadow::before,
.tilting.shadow::after
{
  height: 4px;
  top: initial;
  bottom: 0px;
  width: initial;
}

.tilting.shadow::before {
  left: 0px;
  right: 10px;
  transform: rotate(-3deg);
}

.tilting.shadow::after {
  left: 10px;
  right: 0px;
  transform: rotate(3deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="shadow"></div>

<div class="tilting shadow"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks Rickard. I did try that but the outline is much harsher and needs to be the same as the others on the site

Comment: I updated the answer with another solution.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
box-shadow: 
  5px 0 5px -2px rgba(0,0,0,.5),
  -5px 0px 5px -2px rgba(0,0,0,.5);
```